# How to customize the SBCL REPL?

Tags: common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, sbcl

Is there a way to customize the SBCL REPL in a way that makes it work similar to the CLISP REPL. The standard SBCL REPL isn't really usable on Mac OS X. I can't use the arrow keys or backspace.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use `rlwrap`

If you have MacPorts installed you can get it with

```
sudo port install rlwrap
```

The invoke `sbcl` with

```
rlwrap sbcl
```

Comment: This gives you history, but not tab completion like CLISP.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the people use SBCL REPL with `SLIME`. It gives it by far much more features, then `readline`, that is used in CLISP. If you aren't comfortable with using Emacs, you can try `ABLE` (available through quicklisp) - a very simple editor, that supports some basic REPL features on par with `readline`, but as well has basic code highlighting and built-in Hyperspec.

Answer (score 6):

There's vim+slime (slimv) too, for vim users.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [linedit](http://common-lisp.net/project/linedit/) which is available via Quicklisp. That said, Emacs+SLIME is a real beast. In fact, Firebug is the only thing close to it that I'm aware of.