# How to use key-bindings when using SBCL & Clozure CL on Terminal

Tags: terminal, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp, ccl

I'd like to use key-bindings when I use SBCL & Clozure CL on Terminal.

You can use key-bindings when you use Clisp on Terminal. For example, when you type "Control-p", you can list the history of codes you typed. You can even delete a letter when you type "Control-d".

Do you know how to do the same things on SBCL & Clozure CL on terminal as you can do with Clisp?

I use Macbook, and the OS is 10.11.6.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: https://common-lisp.net/project/linedit/

Comment: http://www.cliki.net/rlwrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the SBCL REPL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109249/how-to-customize-the-sbcl-repl)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I thought it was impossible, but I made it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you install "rlwrap" through MacPorts.

If you run sbcl with "rlwrap sbcl" on Terminal, you can use the key-bindings.

(Note: This answer is based on the article: How to customize the SBCL REPL?

[How to customize the SBCL REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109249/how-to-customize-the-sbcl-repl?noredirect=1&lq=1)
)

Answer (score 3):

These characteristics are present in CLISP since it is integrated with [readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), a package that provides a way to edit the command line in a shell (see the [CLISP summary](http://www.clisp.org/summary.html)). SBCL and CCL are not integrated with readline, so it is not possible to use those commands with them.

The best solution to use them in a powerful environment with lot of commands is through the combination of the [Emacs editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) together with the [SLIME package](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/). Many tutorials exists on the net on how to install and use them. An added benefit is that Emacs and SLIME work for any implementation of Common Lisp.